# copy range from one workbook to another workbook and Paste Data Below the Last Used Row

Tags: excel, vba

[workbooks](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19zhjCGr6G5WVrROvnGFiVuBRD1TckDqU?usp=sharing)

Requests to copy only entries listed in the table
Currently the range is B4: O5 (light blue color)
If there is additional data (for example B4 "O10
Who knew how to copy the above data another time
Each time he will copy only the cells that contain data.
Paste the data here as values (not formulas)
Each time he adds the data at the end of the empty table.

I found a code that works
Just does not past it as values
How can i fix it?
Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("הזמנת עבודה.xlsm").Worksheets("העתקה")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("יומן יומי.xlsm").Worksheets("יומן ראשי")
     
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    
  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("B4:O" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    
  'Optional - Select the destination sheet
  wsDest.Activate
  
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the Excel macro recorder?

Comment: Search for "excel vba pastespecial values"